# Android XML styles

Tags: android, xml

I have the following style in my styles.xml that a toggle button is using. However, i want the toggle button to `fill_parent` but not stretch the image. How can i tell it to center this background image and not stretch it? I'm trying to increase the area the user can click on.

Toggle:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/OtherToggle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/OtherToggle" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="OtherToggle">
    <item name="android:textOn">""</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">""</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">?android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/other_toggle_bg</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you want the image to be centered and never grow any larger, but shrink if necessary  (without changing the aspect ratio) to be completely displayed within the button, I don't think there is a built-in way to do that in Android. You should be able to do that programmatically, though yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you *do* want to stretch the image, but you want to keep the aspect ratio unchanged?

If so, try adding this to your style:

```
<item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
```

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for the other possibilities if centerInside does not do what you want.

Comment: no i wanted to not stretch it, keep it the original size or smaller centered inside.

Comment: See my comment to your question, above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use layer-list as a background drawable for ToggleButton? Create the following xml file and use it in `android:background` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"  
      android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/other_toggle_bg"
      android:gravity="center" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```